# Multiple Activities with NDEF_DISCOVERED

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc, ndef

I have two activities in my app that have the same intent filter of "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED", is there any way of telling the activity programaticaly that I want to start a specific activity and not choose which activity to start upon discovery of ndef? To be more clear, one device is running Activity1 and the second device is running Activity2, whenever I beam from one device or another, the device is asking me which activity to start since they both have the same intent filter.

here is my manifest:

```
<activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Activity1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.activity1" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.activity2" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

Create third, invisible activity (say, `RedirectorActivity`), without any layout and with `NoDisplay` theme (`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`) and excluded from recents (`android:excludeFromRecents="true"`). Assign your `intent-filter` just to that single Activity **alone** (remove filter from others!) and add all the necessary logic in `onCreate()` of said `RedirectorActivity` to launch the right `Activity` from it with regular `startActivity()`. Finally kill RedirectorActivity with `finish()` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give your currently running activity precedence over the other, you should use the NFC foreground dispatch system. See [Advanced NFC: Using the NFC Foreground Dispatch System](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch). (See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940479/how-to-avoid-launching-an-nfc-enabled-app).)

Also you might want to consider if it makes sense for your application to use different types of NDEF records for starting each of your two activities. In that case the sender could decide which activity should be started.